# Javascript function doesn't show correctly format with HTML tags when highlighting matches

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I am trying to create a match strings highlighting matches in the following code. But, somehow, the results or output does not appear in the format I am setting in the div results (UL/LIs). Actually, I'would appreciate your advice to tackle this issue.

```
element.innerHTML = highlightedText;  //if I comment this line, then the text works but, without format
```

```js
function wrapMatchesInSpan(element, searchTerm) {
  var text = element.textContent;
  var regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'gi');
  var matches = text.match(regex);
  if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
    var highlightedText = text.replace(regex, function(match) {
      return '<span class="highlight">' + match + '</span>';
    });
    element.innerHTML = highlightedText; //if I comment this line, then the text works but, without format
  }
}

function search() {
  var searchTerm = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toLowerCase();
  var listItems = document.getElementById("searchResults").getElementsByTagName("li");
  var teamItems = document.getElementById("searchTeams").getElementsByTagName("li");
  var resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");

  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    var listItem = listItems[i];
    var text = listItem.textContent.toLowerCase();

    if (text.includes(searchTerm)) {
      listItem.innerHTML = listItem.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(searchTerm, 'gi'), function(match) {
        return '<span class="highlight">' + match + '</span>';
      });
      listItem.style.display = "list-item";
    } else {
      listItem.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the content
      listItem.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  var hideAllTeams = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < teamItems.length; j++) {
    var teamItem = teamItems[j];
    var teamText = teamItem.textContent.toLowerCase();

    if (teamText.includes(searchTerm)) {
      teamItem.style.display = "list-item";
      hideAllTeams = false;
    } else {
      teamItem.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  if (searchTerm === "") {
    resultsDiv.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    resultsDiv.style.display = "block";
  }

  if (hideAllTeams) {
    teamsDiv.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    teamsDiv.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#results {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#searchResults {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: 430px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#searchInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 425px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#searchTeams {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 425px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#searchTeams li a {
  color: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -2px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#teams {
  color: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -2px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#searchTeams li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #aeadca;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 35px;
  color: blue;
}

ul.scroll {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>NACC-Teams-Locator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="teams">
    <h2>ACC Teams:</h2>
    <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for teams / keywords / services..." oninput="search()">
    <ul class="scroll" id="searchTeams">
      <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#">WMAA</a></li>
      <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#">MobileInf</a></li>
      <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#">MSM</a></li>
      <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#">SECAPPS</a></li>
      <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#">SECAPPS</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="results">
      <h3>Services supported by team:</h3>
      <ul id="searchResults" class="scroll">
        <li style="display: none;">
          <h3>MobileInf:</h3><br> -APIs<br> -Layer 7<br> -Gloo<br> -Gateways<br> -API portal</li>
        <li style="display: none;">
          <h3>Midrange Servers Management (MSM):</h3> -Servers<br> -Filesystem usage<br> -Patching<br> -Root<br> -API portal</li>
        <li style="display: none;">
          <h3>SECAPPS:</h3> -Okta<br> -Passwordsafe<br> -OIG<br> -Forgerock<br> -Evidian <br> -Cyberark<br> -go/password</li>
        <li style="display: none;">
          <h3>Hadoop:</h3> -Hive<br> -Cloudera<br> -Hue/Ambari<br> -Yarn/HDFS<br> -Hadoop Data Movement</b>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    //<img src="" />
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When I try to run your code it gets an error because `teamsDiv` is not defined.

Comment: You never call `wrapMatchesInSpan()`.

Comment: After you type the first letter in the search field, that letter is wrapped in a span. When you type the next character, the `innerHTML` won't match it, because it contains `<span></span>` around the first character.

Comment: So if you type `mobile` it doesn't match `<span class="highlight">m</span>obile`

Comment: Instead of filtering as they type the search term, wait for them to finish and click a "Filter" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the `innerHTML` gets changed every time when `search()` is invoked. From the second call on, the search characters cannot be found because there exists `<span></span>` tags. However, you can circumvent this problem by deleting the corresponding parts from `innerHTML` each time when `search()` is called.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    var listItem = listItems[i];
    var text = listItem.textContent.toLowerCase();

    listItem.innerHTML = listItem.innerHTML.replaceAll('<span class="highlight">', '') 
    listItem.innerHTML = listItem.innerHTML.replaceAll('</span>', '') 

    ...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys, as I am new to Javascript, I never supposed this rule. I will keep it in mind from now on... appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry again... I am still having a problem with my code...  I have to refresh the page to take the highlight, if not refresh it then the highlight does not appear or doesn't appears with format.  What is the reason, or what should I change to to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you typing in order to see this behaviour? Note that there are several problems with your code (see e.g. the first two comments under your question, also I noticed additional problems). My answers shows you the general idea of making it work, not all special constellations are covered by that.

Comment: Yeah, I know my code can be better :s. I m not typing any other thing than text. My first attempt works good. If I delete the text and type another (any other of the group) then it dissapears or just returns with plane text and tags visible just like this way: 

´´´
<h3>Hadoop:h3>
-Hive
-Cloudera
-Hue/Ambari
-Yarn/HDFS
-Hadoop Data Movement
´´´

Comment: The problem is as follows: If you search for certain characters, e.g. "h" or "r", then `search()` finds these characters not only in your results (e.g. in "Hadoop"), but also in the tags of the `innerHTML` (e.g. in `<h3>` or `<br>`). By the replacement of `search()` the tags get destroyed. You have to extend the `replace` call in a sense that existing tags remain unchanged by replacement. Also if you clear the search input box, `search()` gets called with an empty string: `""`. Check whether this case is handled everywhere correct inside `search()`.